# Android Studio Gradle Variable and Task Scope Access

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am trying to figure out how tasks and variables are called and accessed across multiple files. I want to create a custom task and a variable in the 'projects.gradle' file and be able to access it in the module's 'build.gradle' file that will import the 'projects.gradle' file using 'apply from'

Also I would like to know how to call a custom task within the gradle file. For example if I want to call a task before the 'init' phase of gradle project begins

I have added some small sample code to illustrate what I mean.

Edited: moved decleration outside android task.

Main 'project.gradle' File

```
apply plugin: 'android'

// *** DECLARE TASK / VARIABLE HERE

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    useOldManifestMerger false

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.oculono.elpmas'
        minSdkVersion 14

        testApplicationId 'com.oculono.elpmas.tset'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    } 
}
```

Module 'build.gradle' file that imports project.gradle file

```
import groovy.transform.Field;

apply from : '../project.gradle'

// *** ACCESS VARIABLE / TASK HERE

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':CoCo')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a task in `android` block. Declare it after this block and You can access the task in build.gradle without any problems. When it comes to variables - try using an `ext` holder. See [extra properties](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html).

Comment: Sorry just saw that, I have moved it outside of android block. However I would still appreciate any example or url to read more about creating tasks and variables and their scope in general.

Comment: Trust me that this is the best place to start: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking at this for sometime now. Will update this answer soon as I find the solution.